# How to instead of 'query.add_column' add field to entity?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have some sqlalchemy query:

```
>>> items = (
    Company.query
    .add_column(Address.city)
    .join(Company.address)
    .filter(and_(
        ...some filters...
    ))
    .all()
)
>>> items
[(Company(6239), Berlin), (Company(5388), Moscow), ...]
```

How can I modify my query, to put Address.city to entity Company? 
I want it to look as:

```
...
>>> items
[Company(6239), Company(5388), ...]
>>> items[0].city
Berlin
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think you can do it directly in a query without modifying the model.
But you can easily achive this in the code:

```
>>> items
[(Company(6239), Berlin), (Company(5388), Moscow), ...]

>>> # set company
>>> for (_company, _city) in items:
        _company.city = _city
>>> # remove city attribute
>>>> items = [_company for (_company, _city) in items]

>>> items
[Company(6239), Company(5388), ...]
>>> items[0].city
Berlin
```

Comment: I tried and tried, but this was all I could come up with as well :(